# unity android.enableR8=false

Tags: java, c#, android

3.20f
I'm Encountering This Error While Build My Project For Android

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.20f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
> Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Ed

Getting Build for Android
I Reviewed All Codes No Errors But to build

Comment: unity 2021.3.20f

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error, as well as a better version of the error message? I'm not sure the issue you are having is clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.